# Change latex table title to format of "S1 table"

Tags: tables, titles

I am trying to create a table in LaTeX that has the formats "S1 Table". As you can see, in my current MWE code, the table is entitled "Table 1":

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
   \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Here is a practice table}
    {\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Make column width smaller to fit page
     \begin{tabular}{llllll}
     \hline
     Name & Number & Color\\ \hline
     Name1 & Number1 & Color1\\   
     Name2 & Number2 & Color2\\
     Name3 & Number3 & Color3\\
     Name4 & Number4 & Color4\\ \hline
     \end{tabular}}
   \label{s1table}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change this format so that the title is instead "S1 Table". I have seen examples that ask about the reverse "Table S1" which does not work for my solution. I have even seen another example more [similar to my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462227/how-can-i-change-the-names-of-my-supplementary-tables-and-figures-from-figure-s), but the solutions remain unclear to me. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf -- the caption package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}                         % <--- added
\captionsetup[table]{name=SI table,          % <--- define caption name
                     skip=1ex, labelfont=bf} 
begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\caption{Here is a practice table}
\label{s1table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Make column width smaller to fit page
 \begin{tabular}{llllll}
    \hline
 Name  & Number  & Color  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Num.}\\ 
    \hline
 Name2 & Number2 & Color2 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\
 Name3 & Number3 & Color3 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\
 Name4 & Number4 & Color4 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\ 
    \hline
 \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For caption name set up see package documentation, section *2.8 Names*, page 15.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `caption` package and by redefining the label format using the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat` command. In this `#1` will get replaced with the name of the float (table, figure, ...) and `#2` will be replace with the reference number.

The default label format is simple `#1 #2`.

In your case you want the number before the name and prefixed with `S`, so the label format should look like `S#2 #1`

Your MWE would therefore look like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{caption}                            %<---
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Sformat}{S#2 #1}     %<---
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=Sformat}       %<---

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Here is a practice table}
    \label{s1table}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % Make column width smaller to fit page
    \begin{tabular}{llllll}
        \hline
        Name  & Number  & Color  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Num.}\\ 
        \hline
        Name2 & Number2 & Color2 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\
        Name3 & Number3 & Color3 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\
        Name4 & Number4 & Color4 & 1 & 2 & 3   \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

When we refer to the table, we get \cref{s1table}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I am only reformatting the table caption. Also note that if you want to use `cleveref`, you will have to configure that separately to match the caption format or some other one.